# javascript - Check if CSSRule matches Element

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Is there a way to check if a CSS selector ( obtained by `document.styleSheets[666].rules[1984].selectorText` ) matches a specific element ?

I am asking for a cross browser pure javascript solution, but i will consider using jQuery if it is simply done in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For modern browsers, there's [`matchesSelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.mozMatchesSelector). For less modern browsers, you can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) and [walk the DOM](https://gist.github.com/2851541).

**Don't** use jQuery. [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) is enough.

```
Sizzle.matchesSelector(element, selector)
```

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation

Comment: Yes i tend to use jQuery as last resort but the engine will most likely use it anyway ;) thx this is what i wanted

Comment: @n00b: Sizzle is the engine behind jQuery, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

**Searching for a particular CSS rule**

**The below example searches for the "a:hover" rule within the style sheet, and if found, returns a reference to it:**

```
var mysheet=document.styleSheets[0]
var myrules=mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules: mysheet.rules
for (i=0; i<myrules.length; i++){
if(myrules[i].selectorText.toLowerCase()=="a:hover"){ //find "a:hover" rule
targetrule=myrules[i]
break;
}
}
```

ref: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss3.shtml

Comment: this is not what i asked... ;)

Comment: i 1+ this due to `mysheet.cssRules? mysheet.cssRules: mysheet.rules`

Answer (score -2):

It's really simple in jQuery:

```
$(element).is(cssSelector);
```